# Need help identifying the type of cable used in my external portable hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, cable

I purchased my Seagate external hard drive about 4 years ago. Recently I have started experiencing problems with the provided USB cable. So I am guessing it is time to replace it.
However I am just overwhelmed with the type of USB cables out there.

I had no idea that this many types of USB cables are out there. Doing some research on the inscrption on the back of my hard drive and based on several images on the internet, my conclusion is it is a "USB 2.0 female to mini USB 2.0 female cable". Only problem is google returns no exact matches for this type of cable.

The inscription on the back of my hard drive is below:

```
Company:   Seagate
Type   :   Expansion Portable Drive
P/N    :   9SD2A4-500
S/N    :   2GH50JSN
Capacity:  500 GB
```

Now based on some googling using the P/N, I came to the conclusion that it is a "USB 2.0 to mini USB 2.0". Only problem is there aren't any female to female USB cables. My understanding about male/female in USB is, if the USB slot in the cable had pins, it is male, else it is female. Based on this understanding I concluded both are female slots.
Could somebody point out which cable I should be buying?

Comment: Almost all cables are the same - they are "plugs". A standard USB to mini USB should do the job. http://ec-part.com/ebay2013/seagate/harddisk_case/seagate2.5a/seagate2.5usb2.0a_11.JPG

Comment: @Big Chris: Yes, that is precisely my cable! Thanks for the picture.

Comment: Can you snap a picture of the back of the drive and upload it? It'd be a cinch to identify it I could see it.

Comment: @toddlermenot You have male/female backwards; for USB, the "plugs" are male and the jacks are "female": [USB Plugs and Jacks](http://i.imgur.com/iHCEkyL.gif). Unless you're looking at an extension cable, most cables are Male-to-male.

Comment: Just upload a picture and you'll have the answer...

Comment: @Darth Android: Thanks, that clarifies it. I was confusing it with serial/parallel ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments posted here and the wiki article for USB, I have finally found what I need to buy - USB Type A plug to Mini USB Type B plug. To be safe, I have ordered a dual "Y" cable to draw extra power for my Hard drive.
Here is an image of what I ordered: http://www.acp.ca/images/313265.jpg

Comment: Well, the cable arrived today and the plug matches perfectly!. Thanks everybody for the comments.